# search and delete select sms?

Tags: sms

I get all these spam sms from everywhere...

I tried the phone's usual search feature. I search for a spam keyword in my messages, and then try to delete all those messages.

The problem here is that I don't have the option to select all those messages at once and delete them; instead I've to manually delete those messages.

Is there a better way to manage this problem?

Comment: Is the SPAM messages you receive come from the same number or different numbers?

Comment: Its from multiple sources

Answer (score 0):

[SMS Search and Delete](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sbits.smscleaner) have option to select all found messages and delete  them all at once.